# What's the difference between ArrayList & List when generic variance?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I tried two piece of code, and first can be compiled and the second compiler posts an error.

```
class Wraper {
    private fun foo(list: ArrayList<out Number>) {    }
    private fun bar(list: ArrayList<in Number>) {    }

    fun doSome() {
        foo(arrayListOf<Int>())
        bar(arrayListOf<Any>())
    }
}

// error:
// Projection is conflicting with variance of the corresponding 
// type parameter of List. Remove the projection or replace it with '*'
class Wrapper1 {
    private fun foo(list: List<out Number>) {    }
    private fun bar(list: List<in Number>) {    } // error

    fun doSome() {
        foo(listOf<Int>())
        bar(listOf<Any>()) 
    }
}
```

Why is Wrapper1 not right?
What's the difference between ArrayList & List here?

Comment: _List<in Number>_ does not make much sense, since _List_ is not mutable (while _ArrayList_ is). Remove the _in_ or change the type to _MutableList_.

Comment: `List` is declared as covariant (`out`), so it can't be `contravariant` (`in`). `ArrayList` is declared as invariant, so it can become any of above.

Answer (score 1):

- `List` is an interface for a read-only list.
- `MutableList` is an interface that is a subtype of `List` but also supports mutation of the collection.
- `ArrayList` is a class that implements `MutableList`.

Logically, it doesn't make sense to make a read-only collection contravariant. You can't put something `in` it, because it's read-only.

A more technical explanation:

List is defined as covariant [at the declaration site](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/81be03435141b9bc6d812c2d025845f46b338f9b/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt#L124). That means it is always covariant `out` even when you don't explicitly use the keyword `out` with it in your code. Kotlin, unlike Java, supports [declaration site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance). You can declare a variance for a class or interface's generic type at the declaration of the class/interface itself, such that it automatically applies to anything that uses that class/interface.

If you're coming from Java, you should be aware that the Java `List` interface is analogous to Kotlin's `MutableList`, not `List`. Java doesn't have a read-only List interface.